# How to merge the small S3 files into bigger file ( bigger size file)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hive

I am facing an issue in Spark while reading data as the input partitions are huge and I am getting Slow Down 503 error in Spark.

After checking with AWS team they mentioned this is happening in reading files since the request rate is too high.

One of the solution they provided is to combine small files into Bigger one so we can reduce the number of files. Does anyone knows how to merge the small files in S3 into bigger file ? Is there any utility available for doing this ?

Please note that, I am not referring to small part files under one partition. Say I have Level 1 partition as Created_date and level 2 partition VIN . I have one part file under each VIN, but there are too many partitions for VIN. So I am exploring if we can merge these several VIN's part files in S3  into generic CSV then we can handle this issue of S3 slow down.

Your answers are much appreciated!.

Thanks and regards,
Raghav Chandra Shetty

Answer (score -1):

First off I'm not familiar with "Spark".

Combining files in S3 is not possible. S3 is just a place to put your files as is. I think what AWS support is telling you is that you can reduce the number of calls you make by simply having less files. So it's up to you BEFORE you upload your files to S3 to make then bigger (combine them). Either by placing more data into each file or creating a tarball/zip.

You can get similar if not better speeds, plus save on your request limit, by downloading 1, 100MB file then downloading 100, 1MB files. Then you can start taking advantage of the MultiPart Upload/Download feature of S3.